# ¿Cómo pasar a un commit anterior en otra rama?

Tags: git

En mi proyecto, tengo la rama master y la rama main, en la rama main tengo un commit de actualización de datos, ahora quiero volver a un commit anterior y a la vez mover esa versión del código a una rama nueva.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? He probado a hacer git checkout "numero de commit" pero no se como mover esa versión a una rama nueva.
Muchas gracias

Comment: No queda claro qué pretendes. Una respuesta a esta pregunta si no se aclara bien puede ser peligrosa. Ayudaría que dibujaras un diagrama de cómo están ahora las ramas, y cómo quieres que estén al final.

Answer (score 0):

también puedes pararte en la rama a la que quieres moverle los cambios y hacer pull desde el commit.

```
git checkout nombre-de-la-rama
git pull origin numero-del-commit
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de lo que quieres decir con "volver a un commit anterior". Si lo que quieres decir es que te quieres parar en esa revision (o sea, *volver*) sin mover las ramas que tienes, con el checkout y el ID de la revision basta (vas a quedar en *detached HEAD state*, asi que no te asustes si ves un mensaje al respecto).

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres decir es más bien colocar una rama en esa version, es muy sencillo:

```
git branch una-rama id-de-la-revision
```

Si la rama ya existía y quieres colocarla ahí independientemente de lo que la rama tenga en este momento (y entendiendo que esto puede significar reescribir la historia de la rama):

```
git branch -f una-rama id-de-la-revision
```

Si quieres colocar la rama actual sobre esa revision (y de nuevo, reescribiendo la historia de la rama):

```
git reset --hard id-de-la-revision
```

## Importante

un `reset --hard` es PELIGROSO... asegurate de que no tengas cambios en los archivos que no hayas acometido... usa el stash si fuera el caso para no perderlos